# async parallelLimit runs limit times only once

Tags: javascript, node.js, parallel-processing, batch-processing, async.js

I am trying to make use of async.parallelLimit to update records in my db. I need to do this in a batches of 10 and each time the total records will be 1000. I am trying to understand how can i make use of this asyn.parallelLimit in my code. I looked at some example interpreation and tried but it is running only 10 times and after giving back 10 responses it does not give me next ones. I am trying to query the db by executing the filter and then sending the records into async.parallelLimit and get response of all those records. For now i am just trying to understand the parallelLimit and its working. Here is my code

```
const async = require("async");

module.exports = async (server) => {
  async function data(server) {
    return await resolveData(server);
  }

  function resolveData(server) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      let parcel = server.models["Parcel"].find({
        order: "createdAt ASC",
        include: [
          {
            relation: "parcelStatuses",
          },
          {
            relation: "customerData",
            scope: {
              fields: ["firstName", "lastName", "cityId", "customerId"],
            },
          },
        ],
        limit: 1000,
        skip: 200,
      });
      resolve(parcel);
    });
  }
  // console.log(await data(server));
  var parcelData = await data(server);

  for (var i = 1; i <= parcelData.length; i++) {
    parcelData[i - 1] = (function (i) {
      return function () {
        console.log(i);
      };
    })(parcelData[i]);
  }

  async.parallelLimit(parcelData, 10, function (err, results) {
    if (results) {
      console.log("This is resilt", results);
    } else {
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
};
```

I need my parallelLimit function to just return me the records that my query fetch. I will run the update commands later. Since its returning me only 10 records i want to know what i am doing wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what the `for loop` is supposed to do. I'm guessing you're trying to create functions for each elements of the `parcelData`. An easy way to do that is just `map` over the `parcelData` and return an async function:

```
let async = require("async");

// Your data is here but I used a dummy array with 100 elements
let parcelData = Array(100).fill(0).map((_, i) => i);

// Just a dummy function to wait
function delay(ms) {
    return new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms));
}

// map over array and return an `async` function;
let tasks = parcelData.map(p => {
  return async () => {
    await delay(1000);
    console.log(p);
  }
});

// Finally execute the tasks
async.parallelLimit(tasks, 10, (err, result) => {
    if (err) console.error('error: ', err)
    else console.log('done');
});
```

You can run the code on [repl.it](https://repl.it/) to see it in action. Here's [one](https://repl.it/repls/DeliriousUnpleasantDictionaries#index.js) I made.

Comment: Yes, but you need clarify what you want to do with those records. What do you want to accomplish by rate limiting?

Comment: Cool, glad to hear that.

Comment: I will be running an update command on those records to add a new property in them

Comment: @ahsannissar, if the function that performs the update returns a promise then you can simply return the promise and remove the `async`. Like: `parcelData.map(p => yourUpdateFunctionThatReturnsPromise(p))`.

Comment: It worked perfectly and I was able to update more than 40K records in little above an hour and at the same time keep working on other things. However I update two collections by adding a new property inside them. After that I was able to run filters on one collection without any problem but in the second even though the new property was there but the where query was not working against that property. Is there any specific kind of limitations in parallelLimit that can cause this issue or this issue is caused by some other problem? This is not enough info but if deriz any limitation den plz tell

Comment: @ahsannissar, I don't really know but I can tell you it's very unlikely that `parallelLimit` imposes such a limitation. `parallelLimit` is just a function that you could write yourself as well. It seems to be your database might have not flushed the latest schema migration. I suggest you ask another question specific to that database.